# Simple formatting with tidyjson with R

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I have a simple JSON file which I'm attempting to coerce into an R data.frame.

```
json = "
{ \"objects\":
  {
    \"object_one\": {
      \"key1\"        : \"value1\",
      \"key2\"        : \"value2\",
      \"key3\"        : \"0\",
      \"key4\"        : \"value3\",
      \"key5\"        : \"False\",
      \"key6\"        : \"False\"
    },

    \"object_two\": {
      \"key1\"        : \"0.5\",
      \"key2\"        : \"0\",
      \"key3\"        : \"343\",
      \"key4\"        : \"value4\",
      \"key5\"        : \"True\",
      \"key6\"        : \"True\"
    }
  }
}
"
```

and I simply want to extract the name of each object as a index key (or rowname), create column names from the keys and spread the values.

Unfortunately I've had no luck unpicking the syntax.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure on your desired output, but you can use `jsonlite::fromJSON` to extract the data, and `data.table::rbindlist` to put it into a `data.table`

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

rbindlist(fromJSON(json))

#     object_one object_two
# 1:     value1        0.5
# 2:     value2          0
# 3:          0        343
# 4:     value3     value4
# 5:      False       True
# 6:      False       True
```

---

Based on your comment, another approach that involves some reshaping

```
library(jsonlite)
library(reshape2)

lst <- fromJSON(json)
lst <- lapply(lst[[1]], unlist)

df <- as.data.frame(lst)
df$key <- rownames(df)

df <- melt(df, id = "key")
df <- dcast(df, formula = variable ~ key)
df
#      variable   key1   key2 key3   key4  key5  key6
# 1 object_one value1 value2    0 value3 False False
# 2 object_two    0.5      0  343 value4  True  True
```

Comment: Ideally I want the format to be  a data frame with colnames = c("key1","key2","keyn"...) and rownames to be c("object_one", "object_two") etc

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this with tidyjson, the first is to use `tidyjson::append_values_string` and then `tidyr::spread`:

```
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
json %>% 
  enter_object("objects") %>% 
  gather_keys("object") %>% 
  gather_keys("key") %>% 
  append_values_string("value") %>% 
  tbl_df %>% spread(key, value)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>   document.id     object   key1   key2  key3   key4  key5  key6
#> *       <int>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1           1 object_one value1 value2     0 value3 False False
#> 2           1 object_two    0.5      0   343 value4  True  True
```

The other way is to use `tidyjson::spread_values` to specific each key separately:

```
json %>%
  enter_object("objects") %>%
  gather_keys("object") %>%
  spread_values(
    key1 = jstring("key1"),
    key2 = jstring("key2"),
    key3 = jnumber("key3"),
    key4 = jstring("key4"),
    key5 = jstring("key5"),
    key6 = jstring("key6")
  )

#>   document.id     object   key1   key2 key3   key4  key5  key6
#> 1           1 object_one value1 value2    0 value3 False False
#> 2           1 object_two    0.5      0  343 value4  True  True
```

The advantage of the second approach is that you can (a) specify the types of each column and (b) will be guaranteed to get the same data.frame structure even if the keys change (or are missing) in some documents or objects.